# Background color of button not changing in js

Tags: javascript, html, css, jotform

I'm trying to change the background color of a button once the page is loaded. I'm able to disable the buttons, but the background color doesn't change. I have created this form using JotForm. Here is my code:

```
function Lock(){
     document.getElementById("input_11").disabled = "true"
     document.getElementById("input_11").bgcolor="grey";
}
```

Button I'm trying to change:

```
   <div id="cid_11" class="form-input-wide" data-layout="full">
      <div data-align="center" class="form-buttons-wrapper form-buttons-center jsTest-button-wrapperField">
        <button id="input_11" type="submit" class="form-submit-button submit-button jf-form-buttons jsTest-submitField" data-component="button" data-content="">
          Edit
        </button>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("input_11").disabled = "true"` doesn’t make sense. The `disabled` getter / setter is a boolean, not a string. `bgcolor` isn’t a property that exists on buttons. Why not simply create a CSS rule like `button[disabled]{ background-color: gray; }`?

Comment: .bgcolor is not exist, use .style.backgroundColor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bgcolor is one of those attributes that has become deprecated with the implementation of Cascading Style Sheets (see CSS Backgrounds). [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)

```js
function Lock(){
     document.getElementById("input_11").disabled = true
     document.getElementById("input_11").style.backgroundColor = "grey";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to Stack Overflow. but please use trustable and up to date source like [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org) to document your answers with.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour Thanks for the advice. i only got help from stack overflow, but I am trying my best to help people with my insufficient skills :) i will be careful in the future. Thanks again. (Ah! the part you mentioned was replaced by finding information on the MDN site.)

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be a boolean

```
document.getElementById("input_11").disabled = true
```

That's is the error that happened to you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.